# auto populate column B based on column A options

Tags: excel-formula

In Column A I'd like to list one of many providers and consequently would like Column B to auto populate with the provider's pre-op nurse. There are multiple providers to one pre-op nurse. For instance Providers A, B, C, D, E belong to pre-op nurse X, Providers F, G, belong to nurse Y, and Providers H, I, J, K, L belong to nurse Z.  I tried an IF OR statement but could only get it to work for one nurse, not multiple nurses.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `VLOOKUP` function in Excel.  You can have a separate table for the providers and the pre-op nurses and then populate the Column B by looking up the separate table.